# Ellipse and tangents

Tags: multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Given the ellipse $x^2-xy+y^2=\frac{3}{4}$ I want to determine the points that their tangent is perpendicular to the $x'x$ axis and parallel to the $x'x$ axis.

**Solution**

The points that their tangent is perpendicular to the $x'x$ axis are:

$$A(-1, -1/2), \;\; B=(1, 1/2)$$

However how do we prove this? I set at the ellipse where $x$ the $-y$. Hence $3y^2=\frac{1}{4}$ and we get that $y=\pm 1/2$. However I don't think that this is a rigorous proof. Similarly I know that the points $A'(1/2, 1), \;\; B'(-1/2, 1)$ the tangent is parallel to the $x'x$ axis, but how do I justify this?

Comment: Do you know how to use calculus?

Comment: Calculus for what? I know that the tangent of an ellipse is of the form

$$\frac{x x_0}{a^2}+\frac{yy_0}{b^2}=1$$

and that this particular ellipse after we rotate it by $45$ degress comes to the form:

$${\rm C}: \frac{X^2}{\left ( \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} \right )^2}+ \frac{Y^2}{\left ( \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} \right )^2}=1$$

but I don't see how Calculus comes in.

Comment: I don't know much about conics, but I would solve for $y$ and for $x$ and then differentiate. Is there something wrong with this approach?

Comment: I am trying to avoid that. I guess there must be something else smarter.

Comment: Okay. So I'd wait for someone with better exposure to conics to show up to help you then.

Comment: find the gradient of the tangents after rotating by 45º

Comment: @inspd would you mind explaining what you mean?

Comment: find the equation of the tangents in the form of y=ax+b

Comment: But the tangents are of the form:

$$\frac{x x_0}{\frac{3}{2}}+\frac{yy_0}{\frac{1}{2}}=1$$

Right?

Comment: that's right, after you rotated the ellipse, the points A and B will change

Comment: Hang on a minute. So how do we change the points? I do not remember it.

Comment: $x'=x\cos \left( \theta  \right)+y\sin \left( \theta  \right)$ ,  $y'=y\cos \left( \theta  \right)-x\sin \left( \theta  \right)$ where theta is how much you rotated clockwise (here π/4 or 45º).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider the function $f(x,y) = x^2-xy+y^2-3/4 $. Then $$\nabla f(x,y)= \left(f_x(x,y), f_y(x,y)\right) = (2x -y, -x +2y).$$

Recall that $f_x(x,y), f_y(x,y)$ give the rate of change of $f$ in the direction of $x$ and $y$, respectively. Since we want the tangent to be perpendicular to the $x-$ axis, it is clear (?) that $$f_y(x_0,y_0) =0 \implies x_0 = 2y_0,$$ where $(x_0,y_0)$ is the point of intersection (ellipse and tangent). Since $(x_0,y_0)$ belongs to the ellipse, as well, we may solve the system:
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
x_0 = 2y_0\\
f(x_0,y_0) = 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$
which yields the $2$ points $A(-1,-1/2)$ and $B(1,1/2)$.

---

The concept is the same when the tangent is parallel to the $x-$ axis (which means that the tangent is perpendicular to the $y-$ axis).

Answer (score 1):

By rotating the equation:

$$\frac{x^{2}}{\frac{3}{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{\frac{1}{2}}=1$$

Now to find the new A and B coordinates:

$x'=x\cos \left( \theta  \right)+y\sin \left( \theta  \right)$

$y'=y\cos \left( \theta  \right)-x\sin \left( \theta  \right)$

where theta is how much you rotated clockwise (here π/4 or 45º).

$$A_{r}\left( \frac{-3}{2\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \right)\; and\; B_{r}\left( \frac{3}{2\sqrt{2}},\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{2}} \right)$$

Now when you find the tangents at the new A and B points you will get $$y=x+\sqrt{2}\; and\; y=x-\sqrt{2}$$

The angle of the slope is 45º, so rotate back 45º to the original function and you'll get 90º.

---

I do this calculus way, which could be wrong but here:

Through implicit differentiation:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2x-y}{x-2y}$$

If we put the points $A\left( -1,-\frac{1}{2} \right)$ and $B\left( 1,\frac{1}{2} \right)$ we get, respectively: $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-2+\frac{1}{2}}{0}\; and\; \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2-\frac{1}{2}}{0}$$

So we can see that the slope is infinite (parallel to the y-axis), also $\frac{dx}{dy}=0$ at those points, not $\frac{0}{0}$ or something undefined; so this proves that the tangents at $A$ and $B$ are perpendicular to the x-axis.

Answer (score 1):

If
$x^2-xy+y^2=\frac{3}{4}
$,
then
$0
=2xdx-(xdy+ydx)+2ydy
=(2x-y)dx+(2y-x)dy
$,
so
$\frac{dy}{dx}
=-\frac{2x-y}{2y-x}
$
and
$\frac{dx}{dy}
=-\frac{2y-x}{2x-y}
$.

If
$dy/dx = 0$,
$y = 2x$
so
$\frac34
=x^2-2x^2+4x^2
=3x^2
$
or
$x=\pm\frac12$
and
$y = \pm 1
$,
with the same sign
for $x$ and $y$.

If
$dx/dy = 0$,
$y = x/2$
so
$\frac34
=x^2-x^2/2+x^2/4
=3x^2/4
$
or
$x=\pm 1$
and
$y = \pm 1/2
$,
with the same sign
for $x$ and $y$.